# Using a self join to update NULL values in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update

So I have a table with propertyaddress values missing, although the ParcelID column can be used to identify the value. How do I perform a self-join in sqlite to update the NULL values with their true propoertyaddress values?

I tried the following code

```
SELECT a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
FROM housing_data a
JOIN housing_data b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.[UniqueID] <> b.[UniqueID]
WHERE a.PropertyAddress is null;


UPDATE a
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
FROM housing_data  a
WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL;
JOIN housing_data  b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.[UniqueID] <> b.[UniqueID]
```

This code throws an errors

Comment: Move your `WHERE` below the `JOIN` on the `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the `UPDATE FROM` syntax:

```
UPDATE housing_data AS d1
SET PropertyAddress = d2.PropertyAddress
FROM housing_data AS d2
WHERE d2.ParcelID = d1.ParcelID AND d1.PropertyAddress IS NULL AND d2.PropertyAddress IS NOT NULL;
```